# How to get listbox elements in a list? wxpython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using wxpython and I would like to get all the elements in the listbox and returned in a list.

(Almost like the Oposite of the "Set" function)

Example:

Listbox has
Dog 
Cat
Fun

The function should return ["Dog","Cat","Fun"]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.GetItems()

This function can get all elements in your Listbox as a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a GetStrings() function.

```
listBoxList = yourListBox.GetStrings()
```